# Handling PyLint Warning of Inconsistent Return Statement

Tags: python, pylint

I'm running PyLint on some code and I'm getting the warning of "Either all return statements in a function should return an expression or none of them should. (inconsistent-return-statements)."

Here is the code I have:

```
def determine_operand_count(opcode_form, opcode_byte):
  if opcode_form == OP_FORM.VARIABLE:
    if opcode_byte & 0b00100000 = 0b00100000:
      return OP_COUNT.VAR

    return OP_COUNT.OP2

  if opcode_form == OP_FORM.SHORT:
    if opcode_byte & 0b00110000 == 0b00110000:
      return OP_COUNT.OP0

    return OP_COUNT.OP1

  if opcode_form == OP_FORM.LONG:
    return OP_COUNT.OP2
```

Here "OP_FORM" and "OP_COUNT" are Enums defined earlier in the code.

To me, that code is very readable code and I guess I'm curious what the warning from PyLint is complaining about. In every condition that I have, an "OP_COUNT" type is returned. In fact, if any of these conditionals weren't returning an OP_COUNT, my code would be failing entirely.

This seems to be a warning about my "return statements", suggesting that some aren't returning any sort of expression. But that's clearly not true (so far as I can see) as each return statement is returning something. So I'm guessing this has to do with implied returns?

But to that point, in my original code I actually held "else" clauses for my internal `if` statements. But when I did that, PyLint gave me another warning: "Unnecessary 'else' after 'return' (no-else-return)."

I did see the following: "[How to fix inconsistent return statement in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54784893/how-to-fix-inconsistent-return-statement-in-python)", but that didn't seem to reflect the situation in my code.

So it's unclear to me how to satisfy PyLint in this case since the code clearly works and seems to be doing what the warning suggests I need to be doing. Given that, I suspect I'm missing something obvious but that I currently lack the intuition for spotting. Any help to get me spotting what I'm missing would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pylint complains about what is happening when you reach the very end of the function.  What should happen at the end of the function?  (added a return and the warning goes away)

```
def determine_operand_count(opcode_form, opcode_byte):
    if opcode_form == OP_FORM.VARIABLE:
        if opcode_byte & 0b00100000 == 0b00100000:
            return OP_COUNT.VAR
        return OP_COUNT.OP2

    if opcode_form == OP_FORM.SHORT:
        if opcode_byte & 0b00110000 == 0b00110000:
            return OP_COUNT.OP0
        return OP_COUNT.OP1

    if opcode_form == OP_FORM.LONG:
        return OP_COUNT.OP2

    return OP_COUNT.UNKNOWN
```

This code should work, but in my experience is kind of fragile over time because of the indentation.  An alternative is to write it as:

```py
def determine_operand_count_v2(opcode_form, opcode_byte):
    def variable_form(opcode_byte):
        if opcode_byte & 0b00100000 == 0b00100000:
            return OP_COUNT.VAR
        return OP_COUNT.OP2

    def short_form(opcode_byte):
        if opcode_byte & 0b00110000 == 0b00110000:
            return OP_COUNT.OP0
        return OP_COUNT.OP1

    def long_form(_):
        return OP_COUNT.OP2

    opfcn = {OP_FORM.VARIABLE: variable_form,
             OP_FORM.SHORT: short_form,
             OP_FORM.LONG: long_form}

    return opfcn[opcode_form](opcode_byte)
```

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes sense. In this case, I now see my failure of thought. This particular code would never get executed if there wasn't an OP_FORM already. So this method *should* never have a situation where it could an OP_COUNT of UNKNOWN because that could only happen if the opcode_form was not generated to be one of those I have. But if the opcode_form was not found, this method would never be called. BUT -- that's intent; not necessarily realization. And PyLint is rightfully calling me on that.

Comment: And, to be sure, adding your suggestion does in fact resolve the warning.

Comment: You can nest functions within one another? What would be the advantage of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

In your case, it might happen for 2 reasons:

1) Your variable name case is for some reason inconsistent: `opcode_Form` (with uppercase "F") in first `if` statement (probably you just have mistyped it, since you also have `=` instead of `==` at the very same place) and `opcode_form` (with a lowercase "f") in all other places.

2) More likely, since `opcode_form` is not type-hinted as being an `OP_FORM` enum instance, it actually can be of any value, and the final `else` (for the case when `opcode_form` is neither `OP_FORM.VARIABLE` nor `OP_FORM.SHORT` or `OP_FORM.LONG`) is missing. So, for example, if `opcode_form` is some string `"string"`, the function will actually return nothing.

Comment: Thank you. That uppercase "F" was a mistake in typing on my part. It's not like that in the code. I have updated my original code to show that but thank you for pointing it out as it shows the danger of transcribing code rather than just copying it.

Comment: Regarding the type hinting, that's interesting. I did try to add this: `def determine_operand_count(opcode_form: OP_FORM, opcode_byte: int)` to the function header. (If I'm understanding you correctly about type hinting.) That still returns the same PyLint warning.